# Jquery Traversing

Tags: jquery

I am using cloning method to clone a TR and append it to a table. The TR has a textbox and linkbutton(addmore). on click of this link button a new textbox should be shown along with the link button and current linkbutton should be hidden.

How to know that the addmore link is from last row/index. Is it possible to get to know Index if the row is cloned.

Need Help. TIA

Also other than  :last and :first what are all the properties do we have? If the controls are produced dynamically how to find the last but not the one?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.addMore').parent('tr').is(':last')) {
    alert('I am in the last row');
}
```

Assuming your add more links have a class of **addMore**.

Comment: I suspect that 'last' refers here to 'original' rather than 'final' - hopefully sagar can clear this up.

Comment: @ozan last refers to the final TR only . Its working fine.

Do we have like :previous? or where to get to know about these properties. can you provide some useful uRL pls.

Comment: Okay, it wasn't clear to me. The docs for selectors are at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors, but there is no :previous selector because it doesn't make sense to have one - previous relative to what? You will need to use the prev() method on the appropriate jquery object instead.